# When author, date fields blank: remove whitespace between header and text

Tags: spacing, titles

I'm creating a document with KOMA-Script's `scrartcl`, the typical outcome would look something like

[image: with-author]

Now, I would like to leave the date and the author fields blank. This results in a lot of whitespace between the last line of the title and the actual text

[image: noauthor]

I could manually fiddle with negative `vspace`, but there must be a cleaner solution for it.

Minimal code to reproduce the last figure.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\subject{Summer school 2013}
\author{}
\date{}

\title{Exercise sheet 1}
\subtitle{Numerical Optimization: Basics}
% =============================================================================
\begin{document}
\maketitle

random text random text random text random text random text random text random
text random text random text random text random text random text random text
random text random text random text random text random text random text random
text

\end{document}
% =============================================================================
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you redefine the command `\@maketitle` that prints the titlepage information removing the parts for author and date, or rather just printing the fiedlds you are interested in:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{\null\vskip 2em
\begin{center}
  \ifx\@subject\@empty \else
    {\subject@font \@subject \par}
    \vskip 1.5em
  \fi
  \titlefont\huge \@title\par
  \vskip .5em
  {\ifx\@subtitle\@empty\else\usekomafont{subtitle}\@subtitle\par\fi}%
\end{center}
\vskip 2em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\subject{Summer school 2013}
\title{Exercise sheet 1}
\subtitle{Numerical Optimization: Basics}
\maketitle

Text in document body.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This ignores the `\titlehead`.

Comment: @Nico  Indeed it ignores several other fields.  I have rephrased my description of the answer.  The principal is the same in any case: take the standard definition of `\@maketitle` from `scrartcl` class and remove the parts you are not interested in.